# angular JS 2.0 for business application

Tags: angularjs

We are doing the technology evaluation for new application: 
- Is Angular JS 2.0 ready for production version? 
- What about the old directives such as Google Map, Multi-lingual etc, will these work currently with Angular JS 2.0, architecture style guide etc is not available.

What are the tradeoffs.

Thanks,
Dhananjay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are doing the same thing at the moment and my current view is no, it's not ready.  That's not based on the technology, but more on the lack of good examples and learning resources from the community, and also based on the fact that the Angular 2 documentation is currently unfinished (e.g. [the tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) and [testing documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/)).

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS 2 is still in beta. You can test the new sintax and features, but it is no support yet by the old modules (also because most of concept have been rewritten, such as directives that become components).

More on https://angularjs.org/